# Findings distinct sub strings using Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm

Tags: java, string, algorithm, pattern-matching

I am just learning KMP string matching algorithm to find the total occurrance a pattern in s given string. My partial code is as follows, implemented in java:

```
void kmpMatcher( string text, string pattern) {
    int counter = 0;
    int n=text.length();
    int m=pattern.length();
    int [] pi = computePrefix(); // computes the prefix array
    int q = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        while(q > 0 && pattern.charAt(q) != text.charAt(i)) q = pi[q-1];
        if (pattern.charAt(q) == text.charAt(i)) q++;
        if (q==m) {
            out.println(i-m+1);
            q = pi[q-1];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    out.println("Total matches: " + counter);
}
```

Is there any way to find the total number of distinct sub-strings in the given input text string using the above function? what will be the logic to find the distinct sub-strings?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-count-the-number-of-distinct-substrings-in-a-given-string-by-the-use-of-the-KMP-prefix-function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `O(N^2)` time (which is better than a naive solution that adds all substrings to, say, I hash table):

1. Let's iterate over all suffices of the string `S`.
2. For each suffix `T` of the string, we can build a `T#S` string and compute the prefix function for it.
3. We can find the number of substrings that are a prefix of `T` and are not a prefix of any longer suffix by looking at the prefix function array and finding the largest `p[i]` such that `i - p[i] < j`, where `j` is the first character of this suffix.
4. Now we just need to sum the number of such substrings over all suffices.

If you need a faster solution (something like `O(N)` or `O(N log N)`), you can use suffix structures (such as a suffix automaton or a suffix array), but these solutions are more complicated.

Comment: what is the meaning of T#s? @kraskevich

Comment: @user7064921 T concatenated with a special character # concatenated with S.